# How can I get my Selenium test to run in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to develop scripts to test an application that I've written. The first script I've created is one that simply log in, verifies a couple things and log out. I can get it to show up in test explorer, but it won't run for some reason. I've checked the output logs and get a couple errors, but not sure where they are pointing to.

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Threading;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://localhost/github/restaurant/login.php"); //nav to page
            Thread.Sleep(2000); // Implicit wait to ensure page is loaded
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='username']")).Displayed); //look for username field
            IWebElement userField = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='username']")); //mapping userfield to username
            userField.SendKeys("admin"); //typing admin into userfield
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='password']")).Displayed); //looking for password field
            IWebElement pwField = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='password']")); //mapping pwField to password
            pwField.SendKeys("password"); //typing password into pwField
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='login']")).Click(); //clicking login btn
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Implicit wait to ensure page is loaded
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='logout']")).Displayed); //look for logout button
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='logout']")).Click(); //clicking logout button
            Thread.Sleep(1000); //implicit wait
        }
    }

}
```

That's my script, the error(s) I get are below. Does anyone have any insight as to what the problem is with the script?

```
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Helpers.DotnetHostHelper.TryGetExecutablePath(String executableBaseName, String& executablePath)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Helpers.DotnetHostHelper.GetDotnetPath()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.GetTestHostProcessStartInfo(IEnumerable`1 sources, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, TestRunnerConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, String runSettings)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyDiscoveryManager.DiscoverTests(DiscoveryCriteria discoveryCriteria, ITestDiscoveryEventsHandler2 eventHandler)
[6/15/2020 2:36:11.594 PM] ========== Discovery aborted: 0 tests found (0:00:00.0241822) ==========
```

Comment: Is chrome even pulling up? What step is it breaking on? I would get rid of the @ symbol on the url. You do not need it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete specflow files from 'TEMP' folder, rebuilding the solution and try again. See how that works out.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with the test runner not being able to consider tests in your assembly for execution. This can be due to the test adapter not being used by your Visual Studio, try to explicitly include it via Nuget Packages.

[image]

Alternatively, just to demonstrate that your code is not defective, you can execute your tests using the mstest console shown below:

[image]

You'll need to specify the test container using the handle /testcontainer:"{path to test assembly}" (the .dll to your project containing your tests located under bin directory)